# Error using checkstyle/google_checks.xml with maven-checkstyle-plugin

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, checkstyle

I am trying to use [checkstyles](https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle) [google_checks.xml](https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/blob/master/google_checks.xml) with [maven-checkstyle-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/). If I use the google_checks.xml with the latest checkstyle intelliJ plugin everything is correct but when I try configurating it via maven-checkstyle plugin I get this error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.13:check (default-cli) on project XX_XX_XX: Failed during checkstyle configuration: cannot initialize module TreeWalker - Unable to instantiate AvoidEscapedUnicodeCharacters:
Unable to instantiate AvoidEscapedUnicodeCharactersCheck
```

My pom.xml looks like this:

```
   <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<properties>
    [...]
    <checkstyle.file.path>develop/checkstyle/google_checks.xml</checkstyle.file.path>
</properties>
[...]
<build>
    <plugins>
        [...]
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.13</version>
            <configuration>
                <configLocation>${checkstyle.file.path}</configLocation>
                <failOnViolation>false</failOnViolation>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <configLocation>${checkstyle.file.path}</configLocation>
                <failOnViolation>false</failOnViolation>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
```

Do you guys have some suggestions about what could be wrong?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

fixed this by updating the checkstyle-dependency manually to the [latest stable version](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.puppycrawl.tools/checkstyle):

> ```
>         <plugin>
>             <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
>             <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
>             <version>2.13</version>
>             <dependencies>
>                 <dependency>
>                     <groupId>com.puppycrawl.tools</groupId>
>                     <artifactId>checkstyle</artifactId>
>                     <version>${checkstyle.latest.version}</version>
>                 </dependency>
>             </dependencies>
>             <configuration>
>                 <configLocation>${checkstyle.file.path}</configLocation>
>                 <failOnViolation>false</failOnViolation>
>             </configuration>
>         </plugin>
> ```

Answer (score 4):

Maven [checkstyle plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/) uses checkstyle 5.7 (the first line of plugin description).

Checkstyle 5.7 does not have this check (see [checks package](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.puppycrawl.tools/checkstyle/5.7/com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/checks/package-info.java?av=f) on grepcode).

You need either to disable this check or to wait for official fix of [MCHECKSTYLE-261](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MCHECKSTYLE-261).

Answer (score 1):

I give a demo at

https://github.com/favoorr/Maven-Checkstyle-Multimodule-Use

Multi modules and use Google Chechstyle